# What does spite mean in "spite of despondence" in the poem Endymion by John Keats?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context, poetry, literature

The poem *Endymion* by John Keats reads:

> A thing of beauty is a joy for ever:
>   Its loveliness increases; it will never
>   Pass into nothingness; but still will keep
>   A bower quiet for us, and a sleep
>   Full of sweet dreams, and health, and quiet breathing.
>   Therefore, on every morrow, are we wreathing
>   A flowery band to bind us to the earth,
>   **Spite** of despondence, of the inhuman dearth
>   Of noble natures, of the gloomy days,
>   Of all the unhealthy and o'er-darkened ways
>   Made for our searching: yes, in spite of all,
>   Some shape of beauty moves away the pall
>   From our dark spirits. Such the sun, the moon,
>   Trees old, and young, sprouting a shady boon
>   For simple sheep; and such are daffodils
>   With the green world they live in; and clear rills
>   That for themselves a cooling covert make
>   'Gainst the hot season; the mid-forest brake,
>   Rich with a sprinkling of fair musk-rose blooms:
>   And such too is the grandeur of the dooms
>   We have imagined for the mighty dead;
>   All lovely tales that we have heard or read:
>   An endless fountain of immortal drink,
>   Pouring unto us from the heaven's brink.

I believe it is short for "in spite of", as is later supported by the line " yes, in spite of all ". I am convinced of it.

But my teacher says spite here means 'specks'. Another source says it stands for 'malice'. I asked my teacher how would he explain the  'yes' afterwards. But he could not give a satisfactory answer.

Comment: You are right, your teacher is wrong. See [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt109murruoft#page/630/mode/2up), **Spite, 6.**.

Comment: I would interpret it to mean "malice".  But it's poetic interpretation, and no two people will read it the same.

Comment: (Keep in mind that "in spite of" may not mean what you think it means.)

Comment: Ask your teacher for more information on *specks* for *spite* because you'd like more information on that interpretation/usage. (Because so would I.)

Comment: I've only been interested in English for 60 years and I have no faint idea what your teacher might mean by *specks* in this context. It's nonsense.

Though I never met Keats, I'd stake your teacher's salary that here, *spite of* means *in spite of*, the only difference being poetic licence… 

Further, if we really look at the passage in detail, my suggestion would be not only that they're poetically interchangeable but that Keats should have used *In spite of*.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - But did "in spite of", in Keats' time, mean "without regard to", as it usually does now?

Comment: @Hot Licks - I suppose you will agree that upon expanding, that stanza should read "spite of despondence, spite of the inhuman dearth of noble natures, spite of the gloomy days...",  i.e., 'spite of' is essentially meant to apply to despondence, the inhuman death etc. Now if spite means 'malice', then it will translate to " malice of despondence, malice of the inhuman dearth ...", which to me makes no sense. So please explain your interpretation as malice. (And if you don't agree that the stanza can be expanded as I did, then pray tell what Keats, according to you, wants to say in that stanza)

Comment: You don't think "malice" fits with despondence and inhuman death???

Comment: I agree with you.  Just arguing from the text, the phrase "yes, in spite of" clearly reaffirms the passage just before it which began "Spite of".  So in my mind it seems clear that  the two uses have the same sense.

Comment: Hot Licks, I can't even demonstrate, let alone prove it but why would you doubt Keats' contemporaries used *in spite of* exactly as we do today… which, yes, has broadly the same effect as *without regard to* but the operative word there is *broadly*, isn't it?

I don't suggest *in spite of* means *with malice towards* but it does tend more to than from that…

Comment: Kshitij, I could be wrong and it looks as though you put far too much emphasis on one of several uses for *malice*.

I've no idea whether Keats or Hot Licks would agree…

Comment: I'm not sure why there is any lingering doubt here. Three lines further along, Keats continues in what appears to be a repetitive idiom "yes, in spite of all, Some shape or beauty moves away the pall". Clearly his earlier use of "spite" must be poetic licence for "in spite of". The English of the late-eighteenth century is very close to what we speak today, unlike that of Shakespeare and the KJV bible of almost two centuries earlier.

Comment: @StoneyB It reads to me as though Keats is using _spite_ in the sense of meaning 2 of your reference rather than 6. That is he is saying that **a thing of beauty** is a powerful, almost malicious, force against the negative things in the list following _Spite_. I like the feeling that maliciousness, which is usually negative, becomes positive when directed in opposition to negative forces. The _yes, in spite of_  part is then a reflection and expansion of the first _spite_, not just a restatement of it.

Comment: @BoldBen That is the **origin** of the phrase *(in) spite of*, albeit more in the derivative sense of *defiance* than that of *malice*. Both *spite (of)* and *despite (of)*, without a leading *in*, were used this way well into the 19th century.

Comment: @StoneyB Are you saying that _spite_ without the _in_ is a _force_ which can be personalised, a bit like 'scourge of infidels' or 'hammer of the Scots'? If so the poem says that _a thing of beauty_ is _spite of despondence_ (and the other things in the list) in the way that Edward I was _hammer of the Scots_ and that Churchill could have been described as _spite of the Nazis_. If so that is how I read the poem but it is a bit different from _in spite of_ which is how the questioner read it.

Comment: "In spite of" could be read as "despite".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strongest argument for reading "Spite of despondence" as "In spite of despondence" is, as the poster points out, the follow-up usage of "in spite of" within the same sentence three lines later. Here again is the whole sentence:

> Therefore, on every morrow, are we wreathing
>
> A flowery band to bind us to the earth,
>
> **Spite of** despondence, of the inhuman dearth
>
> Of noble natures, of the gloomy days,
>
> Of all the unhealthy and o'er-darkened ways
>
> Made for our searching: yes, **in spite of** all,
>
> Some shape of beauty moves away the pall
>
> From our dark spirits.

Keats lists four things that might discourage a person from feeling bound to the earth through a love a beauty: (1) despondence; (2) a dearth of noble natures; (3) gloomy days; (4) unhealthy and darkened obstructions. But at both ends of this list he identifies things in opposition to those discouragements—first, the act of creating beauty ("wreathing a flowery band"), and second, the experience of feeling the force of beauty sweep away the cloud of gloom. Both positive things act contrarily and counter to the negative forces—which is to say, both act in spite of them.

I checked a number of books that quote this passage of *Endymion*, and most of them don't provide any commentary on the line in question. This, I think, is because most of them have no question that "Spite of despondence" means "In spite of despondence." I did find three texts, however, that venture a restatement or gloss on the original wording. From Milton Goldberg, [*The Poetics of Romanticism: Toward a Reading of John Keats*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5ywiBNwICLEC&q=%22spite+of+despondence%22&dq=%22spite+of+despondence%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVs5yDl7vXAhVLzlQKHcxsCLw4FBDoAQgvMAI) (1969) [combined snippets]:

> Mind and heart must interact to sprout a soul. Emulating the sweet sonnet, fettered in spite of loveliness, we must wreathe a flowery band to bind us to the earth—**in spite of** despondence or the dearth of noble natures:
>
> > If by dull rhymes our English must be chain'd,
> >
> > And, like Andromeda, the Sonnet sweet
> >
> > Fetter'd, in spite of pained loveliness;
> >
> > Let us find out, if we must be constrain'd,

From [*Origins*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9-ctAAAAYAAJ&q=%22spite+of+despondence%22&dq=%22spite+of+despondence%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVs5yDl7vXAhVLzlQKHcxsCLw4FBDoAQg-MAU), volume 24 (1995) [combined snippets]:

> He goes on to ask, in his classic poem, Are we creating some beauty each day ... **in spite of** despondence or the dearth of noble natures?

And from Keki Daruwalla, [*Poetry Magic 7*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ISQMBkjcSaUC&pg=PA6&dq=%22spite+of+despondence%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5sdPplbvXAhXkxFQKHRNeCw0Q6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22spite%20of%20despondence%22&f=false) (2005), a collection of poetry designed for "the young":

> Spite of despondence, of the inhuman dearth
>
> > [Explanatory note:] SPITE OF DESPONDENCE: in spite of being gloomy

This is not to say that Keats only uses *spite* to mean "in spite of." Michael Becker, Robert Dilligan & Todd Bender, [*A Concordance to the Poems of John Keats*](https://books.google.com/books?id=UNoeDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT2235&dq=%22endymion%22+%22spite+of+despondence%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiou-KKlLvXAhVGyFQKHcDtCgQQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22endymion%22%20%22spite%20of%20despondence%22&f=false) (2016) notes two other occurrences of *spite* in *Endymion*—in Book 3, line 615:

> "Young lover, I must weep—such hellish **spite**
>
> With dry cheek who can tell?

and in Book 3, line 650:

> I saw grow up from the horizon's brink
>
> A gallant vessel: soon she seem'd to sink
>
> Away from me again, as though her course
>
> Had resum'd **in spite of** hindering force—

The "hellish spite" is unmistakably maliciousness, and the later "in spite of" clearly functions in the sense of "notwithstanding."

In books about *Endymion*, the "Spite of despondence" line seems uncontroversial. The few texts that address it at all interpret it as meaning "In spite of despondence," but most don't comment on it at all. The first law of poetry is that nothing is certain, so people who interpret the line differently are exercising their muse-given right to do so. But I think that the poster's reading of the line is the most straightforward and coherent of the various readings that are possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Spite of despondence** is no different from "Sorrow of loss" or "Joy of discovery"

OED Spite:

> A strong feeling of (†contempt,) hatred or ill-will; intense grudge or desire to injure; rancorous or envious malice.

"**Of**" can be glossed as "from; originating in"

**Thus:**

Therefore, on every morrow, are we wreathing

A flowery band to bind us to the earth,

Spite of despondence, of the inhuman dearth

Of noble natures, of the gloomy days,

Of all the unhealthy and o'er-darkened ways

Made for our searching: yes, in spite of all,

Some shape of beauty moves away the pall

From our dark spirits.

**Rough translation:**

Therefore every day we are making a wreath

In order to keep us tied to the earth (to prevent us from developing “spiritual”)

**Spite, which comes from/originates in** despondence, [spite] , which comes from the cruel lack

Of noble natures, [spite,] which comes from the depressing days

which comes from all the vices that are

created for our experimentation: yes, **in spite** of all,

Some shape of beauty moves away the clouds

From our depression.

† now obsolete

Comment: I agree but this answer could be made more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

"Spite" could mean 'in spite' and this makes sense in the context of the line. It maybe that Keats shortened this because of the requirements of metre. In the following, the number after the line indicates the number of syllables in the line:

> Therefore, on every morrow, we are wreathing (11)

> A flowery band to bind us to the earth (11)

> Spite of despondance, the inhuman dearth (10)

> Of noble natures, of the gloomy days (10)

> Of all the unhealthy and o'er darkened ways (11)

> Made for our searching: yes, in spite of all (11)

As one can see there is a regular syllable count here, in pairs.

It can also mean 'malice' as "Malice of despondance" is meaningful and this tone is emphasised by the the lines completion, "the inhuman dearth" and this register and rhythm of tone is continued in "gloomy days" and "unhealthy and o'er darkened ways".

'Speck' makes no meaningful sense whatsover. Perhaps you misheard?